# How to pass a variable into select2 element

Tags: angular, jquery-select2

I want to access at a variable (here called "regex") in the `tagCreation` function but when I want to print it, she's undefined.

I've the following code :

```
var regex = ...;

select2Obj = {
  data: this.selectedValues,
  tags: true,
  tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
  selectOnClose: true,
  placeholder: this.placeholder,
  width: '100%',
  createTag: this.tagCreation,
  templateSelection: this.template,
  theme: 'darkred'
};

tagCreation(params) {
  if (params.term.match(this.regex) === null) {
    // Return null to disable tag creation
    return null;
  }
  return {
    id: params.term,
    text: params.term
  };
}

initSelect2(): void {
  this.select2 = $(this.el.nativeElement)
    .find('select')
    .select2(this.select2Obj)
    ...
}
```

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

define your select2Obj after the component is fully loaded and its view rendered.

For example:

```js
declare const regex: RegExp = /^(330|331|333|334|335|336|337|338|339|360|366|368|340|342|344|345|346|347|348|349|351|320|324|327|328|329|380|388|389|391|392|393|370|350|377|373)[0-9]{6,7}$/i;

export class YourClassName implements AfterInit {

  constructor() {}

  tagCreation(reg, params?) {
    if (params.term.match(reg) === null) {
      // Return null to disable tag creation
      return null;
    }
    return {
      id: params.term,
      text: params.term
    };
  }

  initSelect2(): void {
    this.select2 = $(this.el.nativeElement)
      .find('select')
      .select2(this.select2Obj)
      ...
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    select2Obj = {
      data: this.selectedValues,
      tags: true,
      tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
      selectOnClose: true,
      placeholder: this.placeholder,
      width: '100%',
      createTag: this.tagCreation(regex),
      templateSelection: this.template,
      theme: 'darkred'
    };
  }


}
```

Comment: When I do that, `regex` is `undefined` in `tagCreation()`.

Comment: are you sure that is not initializing tagCreation() before your regex assignment?

Comment: How can I check it ?

Comment: When I add it to `ngAfterViewInit()`, `tagCreation()` is called but `regex` is again undefined.
In the `ngOnInit()`, `tagCreation()` is never called.

Comment: edited again. This works for me. If is still not working you could have some problems in your code part that you've not posted.

Comment: When I use your answer, I have the following problem : `ReferenceError: regex is not defined`

Comment: If I do that, `params` is recognized as undefined.

Comment: Delete params? from function definition